# Which table contains column

Tags: c#, oracle, dataset, metadata

There is procedure which builds a select statement, for example

```
public void GetLog(DataSet dataSet, string tableName, string userCase){
  OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
  cmd.Connection = conn;
  tmpSql = @"select * from table1 t1
  join table2 on t1.key=t2.key 
  where 1=1 and "+userCase
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
  adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
  adapter.Fill(dataSet, tableName);
}
```

both tables constain a column  for example "NAME" and when userCase is like "name='BLABLA'" I have exception "ora-00918 column ambiguously defined". I want to add table name into userCase. How I can get info which table contains this column for add it into var userCase "table1.name='BLABLA'". userCase can contain any column from table1 or table2.  I need to change the procedure so that it gets metadata by sql or by tables name

Comment: If both tables have a column named `NAME` then only a person who knows your data can answer this question for you.

Comment: It's just example and sql and fields  may be other. I want make universal method for build sql.

Comment: Then whatever process is calling this function with `userCase` would have to know the table that the necessary column belongs to

Comment: as I said earlier this is just an example, I need universal method for build sql.  I tried to use DataTableMapping,  DataTableMapping mapping = adapter.TableMappings.Add("table1 ", "table1 "); but mapping  does not containt table description

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do is possible. You might want to consider having distinct methods for distinct queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change sql like

```
tmpSql = @"select * from (select t1.key as t1_key,t2.key as t2_key, t1.name as t1_name,t2.name  as t2_name..... from table1 t1
  join table2 on t1.key=t2.key )
  where t2_name='...'
```

and the condition userCase should be based on alias

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're already passing tableName as Method parameter. If that's the table that contains column from userCase, then you could write something like:

```
tmpSql = @"select * from table1 t1
```

join tablet2 on t1.key=t2.key 
  where 1=1 and "+tableName+"."+userCase

If you have columns with same name in multiple tables, then there's no way for computer to know which one do you mean, unless you specify it (either by passing it as part of userCase, or concatenating it like shown above). If column is in single table, then you have nothing to worry about.

Regards,